# Jetty: Find out which connector was used for incoming Request

Tags: java, servlets, jetty, embedded-jetty

When handling a Jetty response I want to know on which port the request originated on?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Server server = new Server();
    server.setConnectors(new Connector[] {connectorUnsecure, connectorSecure});

    ServletContextHandler handler = new ServletContextHandler();
    handler.setContextPath("/");
    handler.addServlet(MyServlet.class, "/*");

    server.setHandler(handler);
    server.start();
    server.join();
}

public abstract class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected final void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // Find out on which connector port the request came from.
        // (The request.getRequestURL() does not contain the port at all times.)
    }
}
```

When using a custom Handler, I could use something like:

```
public class CustomHandler extends AbstractHandler {

    public void handle(String target, Request baseRequest, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        // baseRequest.getConnection().getConnector().getPort()
    }
}
```

However, I don't want to use a custom handler.

Is it possible to obtain the connector and its port when using a plain HttpServlet?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184286/difference-between-getlocalport-and-getserverport-in-servlets

Comment: Silly me! Thanks, it worked wonderfully.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's 5 methods on [`javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) that might be of use for you.

- [`.getLocalAddr()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getLocalAddr()) - the server address the request is being processed on (could be IPv4 or IPv6)
- [`.getLocalPort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getLocalPort()) - the server port the request is being processed on
- [`.getRemoteAddr()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRemoteHost()) - the client address the request is being processed on (could be IPv4 or IPv6)
- [`.getRemotePort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRemotePort()) - the client port the request is being processed on
- [`.getHeader("Host")`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getHeader(java.lang.String)) - the requested HTTP Host (and port) that the client *thinks* its talking to. (part of the HTTP spec, and especially useful for virtual hosts)

Note: the HTTP Request Host header can also be obtained via the [.getRequestURI()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURI()) method.

```java
String serverAddr = URI.create(request.getRequestURI()).getHost();
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! As Simone posted in a previous response, getLocalPort() was the one of interest for me.